# How do I get n processes to wait using semaphore?

Tags: c, fork, wait, semaphore

I'd need some of your help again...

I'm trying to develop a Program in C which does the following:

`managerProcess` creates `NUM_PROCESSES` `Student` processes.

Each `Student` Process once it gets created, waits for other `Student` processes to be created until number of processes created.

When all `Student` Processes are created, they start to do their job, which is not relevant to this question.

Important thing: Each `Student` Process must have same code.

Here's some code I wrote:

```
pid_t run_child(Student s, int index, int (*function)(Student s, int index)){
    pid_t  p;
    p = fork();
    if (p == -1) 
        return -1;
    else if (!p)
        exit(function(s, index));
    else 
        return p;
}



int child_process(Student s, int index){
    //This printf is executed NUM_PROCESSES times 
    printf("Child Process %d has been created\n", getpid());
    //Once reached this point each Process running this function will do other things

    /*SOME OTHER CODE STUDENT PROCESSES EXECUTE*/
    printf("%d Student Processes Created\n", NUM_PROCESSES);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

At last `main.c` File:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    pid_t  child_pid[NUM_PROCESSES];
    int    child_status[NUM_PROCESSES];
    int i;
    int status;
    status = EXIT_SUCCESS; 

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_PROCESSES; i++) {
        Student s;
        child_pid[i] = run_child(s, i, child_process);
        if (child_pid[i] == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot fork a child process: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
            status = EXIT_FAILURE;
        } 
    }
    return status;
}
```

As you may notice, code above creates `NUM_PROCESSES` `Student` Processes and that's good. 
What I want to do is that each `Student` Process waits for all `NUM_PROCESSES` `Student` Processes creation and only then they start doing other things.
How can I achieve that using `Semaphore` developed below?

```
//Creates ONE Semaphore
int createSemaphore(key_t semaphoreKey){
    int semaphoreId = semget(semaphoreKey, 1, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    if(semaphoreId == -1){
        printf(RED "Semaphore Creation failed\n"RESET);
        return -1;
    }
    return semaphoreId;
}

//Creates a set of Semaphores with numSems Semaphores
int createSemaphoreSet(key_t semaphoreKey, int numSems){
    int semaphoreId = semget(semaphoreKey, numSems, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    if(semaphoreId == -1){
        printf(RED "Semaphore Set Creation Failed\n" RESET);
        return -1;
    }
    return semaphoreId;
}

//Decreases semaphores value by 1
void semaphoreWait(int semaphoreId, int semaphoreNumber){
    struct sembuf buffer;
    buffer.sem_num = semaphoreNumber;
    buffer.sem_op = -1;
    buffer.sem_flg = 0;
    int done = semop(semaphoreId, &buffer, 1);
    if(done == -1){
        printf(RED "Wait on Semaphore %d failed\n" RESET, semaphoreNumber);
        return;
    }
}

//Increments semaphore's value by 1
void semaphoreSignal(int semaphoreId, int semaphoreNumber){
    struct sembuf buffer;
    buffer.sem_num = semaphoreNumber;
    buffer.sem_op = 1;
    buffer.sem_flg = 0;
    int done = semop(semaphoreId, &buffer, 1);
    if(done == -1){
        printf(RED "semaphoreSignal Failed on Semaphore %d\n" RESET, semaphoreNumber);
        return;
    }
}
```

Hope I've been clear.
Thank you very much

Comment: Your title is a little misleading, since the question isn't really about the creation of your processes, but the initial synchronization of them. And for that it seems like some kind of [*monitor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)) could be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the System-V flavor of semaphore that you're using, the general scheme would go best like this:

1. The parent process creates or opens the semaphore via `semget()`, and initializes its value to 0 via `semctl()`.
2. The parent forks all the children.
3. Each child performs a decrement-by-one operation on the semaphore via `semop()`.  For example,

   ```
   struct sembuf semops = { .sem_num = 0, .sem_op = -1 };
   int result = semop(semid, &semops, 1);
   ```

   Each child will block until it can perform this operation without making the semaphore's value negative.
4. The parent uses `semop()` to increase the semaphore's value by the number of child processes.  This semaphore operation does not block, and after it completes, all the children will be able to proceed.

   ```
   struct sembuf semops2 = { .sem_num = 0, .sem_op = NUM_PROCESSES };
   int result2 = semop(semid, &semops2, 1);
   ```

There are other combinations of semaphore operations that could achieve what you describe (and more modern flavors of semaphores with which you could perform some of them), but I daresay the above presents the standard System-V idiom for such a task.

Comment: I studied your suggestion, wrote code and works like a charm. 
Thank you very much!